# JTS Geometry.intersects() method produces infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, jts

I'm trying to check whether a Multipolygon intersects with which Polygon in a list, using JTS library. However, the method stucks in an infinite loop and end with an out of heap space error.

The method works fine for pairs that apparently don't intersect. The infinite loop starts when the first pair that's likely to intersect appears.

Here are the coordinate sequence of the two problematic Geometry objects, (GeoJson format):

**Edit 1 - adding the code:**

Multipolygon:

```
[ [ [ [ 24.899993263111575, 60.168590212519007, 0.0 ], [ 24.8921845577913, 60.170930189360085, 0.0 ], [ 24.906727352467691, 60.177129472862902, 0.0 ], [ 24.912750145776748, 60.178210672366426, 0.0 ], [ 24.915824674917332, 60.1759297188066, 0.0 ], [ 24.916581969097017, 60.175298383750082, 0.0 ], [ 24.921993683436096, 60.17592332951083, 0.0 ], [ 24.924298430649159, 60.176277074203171, 0.0 ], [ 24.925777801589089, 60.176578177900481, 0.0 ], [ 24.927069958749666, 60.176812746915481, 0.0 ], [ 24.934606301659603, 60.17770118209701, 0.0 ], [ 24.93829154797028, 60.17943631088842, 0.0 ], [ 24.943101975190991, 60.179746422785151, 0.0 ], [ 24.946157646983945, 60.177893553297686, 0.0 ], [ 24.949063929828164, 60.176872818864446, 0.0 ], [ 24.948884500413151, 60.176763003129317, 0.0 ], [ 24.947435273641268, 60.175810147107796, 0.0 ], [ 24.947645652172458, 60.174545608314318, 0.0 ], [ 24.953922745030216, 60.17465838879788, 0.0 ], [ 24.952114223411215, 60.172614801031834, 0.0 ], [ 24.952535692362105, 60.169038476544031, 0.0 ], [ 24.954301749734213, 60.168843140472724, 0.0 ], [ 24.954352635736257, 60.167875977512914, 0.0 ], [ 24.954382959437606, 60.167722794336058, 0.0 ], [ 24.94618172965189, 60.167514740158367, 0.0 ], [ 24.94537429422477, 60.167437294026875, 0.0 ], [ 24.946805477127789, 60.166445009469363, 0.0 ], [ 24.946239227186837, 60.166289851133151, 0.0 ], [ 24.94605715808019, 60.166369202625063, 0.0 ], [ 24.944895457595461, 60.165955522827154, 0.0 ], [ 24.943796685615666, 60.166732851647168, 0.0 ], [ 24.943804264808218, 60.16695638982231, 0.0 ], [ 24.94339656134855, 60.167013101789991, 0.0 ], [ 24.943005307041311, 60.1672873863494, 0.0 ], [ 24.942815762910648, 60.167233708186423, 0.0 ], [ 24.942650545385295, 60.167130925185603, 0.0 ], [ 24.9407231754085, 60.166436365685314, 0.0 ], [ 24.940722537913366, 60.166342333123318, 0.0 ], [ 24.940730039071539, 60.166232085046666, 0.0 ], [ 24.94054008676806, 60.166146432407373, 0.0 ], [ 24.940689883918264, 60.166032286309964, 0.0 ], [ 24.938850589801866, 60.165384512580708, 0.0 ], [ 24.938374768557253, 60.165445980685028, 0.0 ], [ 24.938302460409481, 60.165202578885371, 0.0 ], [ 24.937168766625486, 60.1648185467416, 0.0 ], [ 24.936325303890971, 60.164523435250963, 0.0 ], [ 24.935515249176746, 60.165055276075314, 0.0 ], [ 24.935162131372266, 60.165067012171299, 0.0 ], [ 24.935243484405692, 60.165243301611966, 0.0 ], [ 24.934771879418953, 60.165604942333808, 0.0 ], [ 24.935697179525107, 60.165921540021522, 0.0 ], [ 24.935678441330882, 60.16607022900051, 0.0 ], [ 24.93562630412751, 60.166223958343842, 0.0 ], [ 24.93432941740414, 60.16639906762866, 0.0 ], [ 24.934086151809726, 60.16643747924013, 0.0 ], [ 24.933996000970303, 60.166879775928571, 0.0 ], [ 24.933494220741714, 60.166503500060202, 0.0 ], [ 24.930639585658206, 60.166879026400828, 0.0 ], [ 24.930477360716871, 60.167021165775722, 0.0 ], [ 24.93012338167825, 60.166940112911924, 0.0 ], [ 24.926990522351048, 60.167324416451343, 0.0 ], [ 24.926831203850465, 60.167593482122442, 0.0 ], [ 24.92584998697993, 60.167800919963199, 0.0 ], [ 24.925440947757817, 60.167842026167428, 0.0 ], [ 24.925464402293027, 60.167636210840456, 0.0 ], [ 24.925057233085131, 60.167426343568081, 0.0 ], [ 24.924638431368617, 60.167314445885701, 0.0 ], [ 24.924653932101634, 60.166777681068048, 0.0 ], [ 24.924239526771945, 60.166656330235163, 0.0 ], [ 24.923909713383374, 60.166769702593491, 0.0 ], [ 24.919742746576386, 60.166669946668634, 0.0 ], [ 24.919486254229472, 60.168947489628216, 0.0 ], [ 24.917865586081348, 60.169052961010145, 0.0 ], [ 24.913389466202162, 60.169206955531649, 0.0 ], [ 24.908339577064975, 60.169298848862468, 0.0 ], [ 24.899993263111575, 60.168590212519007, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 24.936135087425775, 60.173864750028308, 0.0 ], [ 24.935822882124054, 60.173818038029538, 0.0 ], [ 24.935698898369246, 60.173449814747812, 0.0 ], [ 24.935042425364173, 60.172863964505616, 0.0 ], [ 24.934700282784398, 60.172293513337216, 0.0 ], [ 24.934235985164971, 60.171993255866646, 0.0 ], [ 24.93458616422809, 60.171768472366658, 0.0 ], [ 24.935119957047309, 60.171965193243153, 0.0 ], [ 24.935650390363076, 60.171879257705569, 0.0 ], [ 24.936025502093653, 60.171926942487744, 0.0 ], [ 24.936234782914752, 60.171605759312015, 0.0 ], [ 24.937662268667879, 60.172287296440999, 0.0 ], [ 24.936135087425775, 60.173864750028308, 0.0 ] ] ] ]
```

Polygon:

```
[ [ [ 24.94068318546399, 60.17336319841633 ], [ 24.93618043398334, 60.17329314372988 ], [ 24.936039655930326, 60.17553644290522 ], [ 24.940542714024545, 60.17560650391693 ], [ 24.94068318546399, 60.17336319841633 ] ] ]
```

Here's the piece of code used to generate Polygon:

```
    public Polygon toPolygonJTS(GeometryFactory factory,
        LinearRing polygonRingHolder, ArrayList<LinearRing> holeHolder,
        ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinateHolder) {
    if (!this.jtsDrawn) {
        boolean isHole = false;
        // list of points stored in array list
        for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> linearRing : this.geometry
                .getCoordinates()) {
            for (ArrayList<Double> point : linearRing) {
                // add the point to array
                coordinateHolder.add(new Coordinate(point.get(0), point
                        .get(1)));
            }
            if (!isHole) {
                // create a LinearRing for the polygon
                polygonRingHolder = new LinearRing(
                        new CoordinateArraySequence(
                                coordinateHolder
                                        .toArray(new Coordinate[coordinateHolder
                                                .size()])), factory);
            } else {
                // add LinearRing to a list of polygons specifying holes
                holeHolder.add(new LinearRing(new CoordinateArraySequence(
                        coordinateHolder
                                .toArray(new Coordinate[coordinateHolder
                                        .size()])), factory));
            }
            // clear coordinate holder for the next loop
            coordinateHolder.clear();
        }
        // create a polygon and store in object property
        this.polygon = new Polygon(polygonRingHolder,
                holeHolder.toArray(new LinearRing[holeHolder.size()]),
                factory);
    }
    return this.polygon;
}
```

For MultiPolygon:

```
    public MultiPolygon toMultiPolygonJTS(GeometryFactory factory,
        ArrayList<Polygon> polygonList, LinearRing polygonRingHolder,
        ArrayList<LinearRing> holeHolder,
        ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinateHolder) {
    if (!this.jtsDrawn) {
        boolean isHole = false;
        for (ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> polygon : this.geometry.coordinates) {
            for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> linearRing : polygon) {
                for (ArrayList<Double> point : linearRing) {
                    coordinateHolder.add(new Coordinate(new Coordinate(((Double) (point.get(0) * 100000)).intValue(), ((Double) (point
                        .get(1) * 100000)).intValue())));
                }
                if (!isHole) {
                    polygonRingHolder = new LinearRing(
                            new CoordinateArraySequence(
                                    coordinateHolder
                                            .toArray(new Coordinate[coordinateHolder
                                                    .size()])), factory);
                } else {
                    holeHolder
                            .add(new LinearRing(
                                    new CoordinateArraySequence(
                                            coordinateHolder
                                                    .toArray(new Coordinate[coordinateHolder
                                                            .size()])),
                                    factory));
                }
                coordinateHolder.clear();
            }
            // create a polygon and add to a list
            polygonList.add(new Polygon(polygonRingHolder, holeHolder
                    .toArray(new LinearRing[holeHolder.size()]), factory));
        }
        // create multipolygon from list of polygon, and store in object
        this.multiPolygon = new MultiPolygon(
                polygonList.toArray(new Polygon[polygonList.size()]),
                factory);
    }
    return this.multiPolygon;
}
```

Check if two Geometrys intersect:

```
    public boolean collidesJTS(MapSquarePolygonFeature mapsquare, GeometryFactory factory,
        ArrayList<Polygon> polygonList, LinearRing polygonRingHolder,
        ArrayList<LinearRing> holeHolder,
        ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinateHolder) {
    return this.multiPolygon.intersects(mapsquare.toPolygonJTS(factory, polygonRingHolder, holeHolder, coordinateHolder));
}
```

**Edit 2:** The code runs well if I create distance from the two Geometrys, e.g. multiply the Polygon's x and y by 10.

Comment: Could we see the code that invokes `intersects`? That may help diagnose the problem.